# pip install mysqlclient error django

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip, windows-10, mysql-connector-python

I am currently using MySQL 8.0 as database for my Django project. I am working with Python 3.6 version and have installed `pip` to load python modules from internet. I haven't faced issues while loading packages other than mysqlclient using pip.

I issued the command `pip install mysqlclient` and end up with following message and installation gets aborted:

```
"c:\users\anirudh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Anirudh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xer9o7aw\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Anirudh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-t3br6ckm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Anirudh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xer9o7aw\mysqlclient\
```

I am using visual studio 2017 and followed the link below fix this issue but no luck.

https://dimitri.janczak.net/2017/05/20/python-3-6-visual-studio-2017/

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install `mysqlclient` using pip. But i did not succeed. I was able to install it using:

```
conda install mysqlclient
```

And it worked fine for me.

Comment: Will the system still be able to access this if the other applications such as Django were installed using pip?